# Trying to reading a file line by line in Java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Hi guys i'm trying to create an array of type Question but i think i have a problem in counting the questions in the text file,
the text file has a line then empty line then another line then an empty line and so... And i get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line
>   found at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source) at
>   Question.countQuestions(Question.java:27) at
>   Question.readAllQuestions(Question.java:44) at test.main(test.java:7)

an example of the text file :

[enter link description here](http://textuploader.com/ddglr/)

here's my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question {
private String q; private String a;
private String b; private String c;
private String d; private String cA;

public Question(String q, String a, String b, String c, String d, String cA) {
    this.q = q; this.a = a; 
    this.b = b; this.c = c;
    this.d = d; this.cA = cA;
}

private static int countQuestions() throws FileNotFoundException{
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner file = new Scanner (new File("testBank.txt"));
    while(file.hasNextLine()){
        // check if line empty
        String text = file.nextLine();
        while(!text.equals("")){
            file.nextLine();
        }
        file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();

        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

public static Question[] readAllQuestions() throws FileNotFoundException{
    int numberOfQuestions = countQuestions();
    Question [] allQuestions = new Question[numberOfQuestions];
    Scanner file = new Scanner (new File("testBank.txt"));
    for (int i = 0 ; i < allQuestions.length ; i++){
        String text = file.nextLine();
        String q = "";
        while(!text.equals("")){
            q += file.nextLine();
        }
        String a=file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        String b=file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        String c=file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        String d=file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        String cA=file.nextLine();
        file.nextLine();
        Question question = new Question(q,a,b,c,d,cA);
        allQuestions[i] = question;
    }
    return allQuestions;
}
```

Comment: Inside the inner `while` loop you are not updating `text`, but you are using it in the loop condition, so the result of evaluating the condition will not change during the loop, which will either loop forever or not even once, depending on what value `text` had before entering the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, This will help..!

To avoid Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found use

```
while(text.equals(" "))
{
   file.nextLine();
}
```

instead of

```
while(!text.equals(""))
{
  file.nextLine();
}
```

and write your code in try..catch block eg.

```
private static int countQuestions() throws FileNotFoundException{
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner file = new Scanner (new File("testBank.txt"));
    while(file.hasNextLine()){
        try
        {
            // check if line empty
            String text = file.nextLine();

            while(text.equals(" ")){
                    file.nextLine();
            }
            file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();

            counter++;
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            //Found End of File
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Check this one

```
public static Question[] readAllQuestions() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    int numberOfQuestions = countQuestions();
    Question [] allQuestions = new Question[numberOfQuestions];
    Scanner file = new Scanner (new File("testBank.txt"));
    try
    {      
        for (int i = 0 ; i < allQuestions.length ; i++)
        {
            String text = file.nextLine();
             String q = "";
            while(text.equals(" ")){
                file.nextLine();
            }
            q += text;
            file.nextLine();
            String a=file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            String b=file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            String c=file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            String d=file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            String cA=file.nextLine();
            file.nextLine();
            Question question = new Question(q,a,b,c,d,cA);
            allQuestions[i] = question;
        }
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        //Found End of File
    }
    return allQuestions;
}
```

Comment: same problem Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at Question.countQuestions(Question.java:32)
 at Question.readAllQuestions(Question.java:44)
 at test.main(test.java:7)

Comment: it worked but, i faced another problem, when trying to assign the variables for the questions and the answers in the second method readAllQuestions()

Comment: it simply does not show anything when i run my code
    Question[] Array = Question.readAllQuestions();
  Array.toString();

(i have created a toString method already to return question and 4 choices)

Answer (score 0):

In the below code you are calling file.nextLine() without checking if it has next line. Also if I am not wrong you might want to call it once only inside the loop.

```
private static int countQuestions() throws FileNotFoundException{
int counter = 0;
Scanner file = new Scanner (new File("testBank.txt"));
while(file.hasNextLine()){
    // check if line empty
    String text = file.nextLine();
    while(!text.equals("")){
        file.nextLine(); // no check if new line exist
    }
    file.nextLine(); 
    file.nextLine();
    file.nextLine();
    file.nextLine();
    file.nextLine();
    file.nextLine();
    file.nextLine();
    file.nextLine();
    file.nextLine();
    file.nextLine();

    counter++;
}
```

Use below code instead

```
while(file.hasNextLine()){
    // check if line empty
    String text = file.nextLine();
    while(!text.equals(" ")){
         counter++;
    }       
}
```